# What's your development environment for JBoss 5?

Tags: java, jboss, hardware, requirements

I’m developing application with JBoss AS 5 with a special configuration according to my needs (Web container, ejb3 and JMS)

IDE: My Eclipse 6.5

Hardware: Apple macbook 2.3Ghz, 2Gb ram

MyEclipse hot deploy works fine, but when I need to change method’s sign or introduced new classes the system ask for a reboot of the JBoss. This slows the development process a lot. Moreover, the JBoss consumes a lot of memory (starting footprint about 500mb!). I’m wondering if there is a way to decrease the requirements for a developer environment or I just need to switch to a more powerful hardware?

Comment: Looks fine to me. We run Eclipse + JBoss on old Xeon WinXP machines with 2GB, and it's fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest a more powerful hardware.

My computer specs

- Macbook pro, about the same as yours
  but 2.4GHz -> NetBeans + JBoss 4.0.x
- Hackint0sh, Quad Core 2.93GHz, 4GB
  memory -> IntelliJ + JBoss 5